# The first parameter of loadScript() and loadStyle() must be an LWC component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, javascript-controller

I have a strange problem with the component and I don't know what more can i do, **I'm having this problem whenever I put the lwc inside the recordPage of a custom object** but in a standard recordPage object it work also in IE 11, but in Firefox & Chrome no.

This is what it looks like in **Lightning app builder**:

[image]

But when I go back to the record page I find this problem:

[image]

When I display the same code in another sandbox, the component works perfectly.

How do I load the static resource styles:

```
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import styles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/rep_sr_datatableStyles';

....

 renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, styles)
    ]).then(() => {
        window.console.log('Files loaded.');
    }).catch(error => {
        window.console.log("Error " + error.body.message);
    });
}
```

rep_sr_datatableStyles => is a static resource that it have just a file .css

Comment: I recently discovered that "this" doesn't parse as an LWC component in a child component. The answer is to move the loadScript/loadStyle calls to the parent - at least that's what worked for me. Typically, you would pre-load all the libraries you need in your app right up front anyway. That said, it would be nice if it could be lazy-loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in salesforce. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SHoDQAW

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to specify the file inside the static resource.

If the css file were named `style.css` inside the zip / static resource, it'd look like this:

```js
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import styles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/rep_sr_datatableStyles';

....

 renderedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, styles + '/style.css') //specified filename
    ]).then(() => {
        window.console.log('Files loaded.');
    }).catch(error => {
        window.console.log("Error " + error.body.message);
    });
}
```

Also, you could do away with the `Promise.all` if you're really only needing to only load the one file.

```js
loadStyle(this, styles + '/style.css')
  .then(() => console.log('files loaded'))
  .catch(error => console.log("Error " + error.body.message))
```

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_third_party_library

Comment: If you load just a file in the static resource you can use "loadStyle(this, styles)", but if you look the first image you can se that the styles is applied. The problem that i have is that if I put the component in a recordPage of a custom object I get the error(Second image) in Chroome and Firefox, but in IE11 it works everywhere.

Comment: Gotcha. I made an lwc and uploaded css file without zip and it worked via app builder and on a record page. I made a gist of that lwc, curious to see if it works for you too: https://gist.github.com/jsmithdev/53e2bcdbd077f7e2fed5ee8a0ee1924f

Comment: Try displaying it on a custom object record page. Because if I implement it in Account, it works, but if I create a tab for a custom object, the "loadStyle" function does not work.

Comment: I made sobject Unicorn, made tab and seems to be working: https://i.imgur.com/w2Xl1wD.png

Comment: Pff, I don’t understand anything. I’m having this problem whenever I use it on a custom object. It can be by the configuration of the project, the version of the sandbox or the Visual Studio?

Comment: For me, I just used my dev org, but might be a good use case to create a scratch org to test. If it's tried there and it works then you'd have something to compare versions / config. I can't really see how vs code could be the culprit so I'd go for testing version / config. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do you have `template` defined somewhere in the main class? I was having the same issue but than then I debugged platformResourceLoader.js and realized that it was looking for `cmp.template.host.ownerDocument` (`cmp` in that context is the `this` that you put in the loadStyle() or loadScript()). I removed the `template` definition and it was fine.